# Credit Card Mask kata on CodeWars - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

These are the instructions for the kata I'm working on:

> Usually when you buy something, you're asked whether your credit card
> number, phone number or answer to your most secret question is still
> correct. However, since someone could look over your shoulder, you
> don't want that shown on your screen. Instead, we mask it.
>
> Your task is to write a function maskify, which changes all but the
> last four characters into '#'.

I'm having a hard time figuring out why this code is able to print out the correct answer

```
let maskify = cc => console.log('#'.repeat(cc.length - 4) + cc.substr(-4));
```

But the following code only returns "RangeError: Invalid count value at String.repeat ()"

```
let maskify = cc => {
  return '#'.repeat(cc.length - 4) + cc.substr(-4);
}
```

Comment: @Bravo Yeah, I didn't expect it to work either. I was just trying different configurations to see if my logic was solid and that went through. I'm just not sure why I can get the result I want in the console, but not when returning the function?

Comment: I misunderstood the nature of the issue with my first comment, but if you add `console.log(cc.length)` in that second function, what does it produce

Comment: 16, which is the length of the first test case string

Answer (score 0):

How are you running your function? I ran your function in repl.it with some sample input, and it works fine.

```
let maskify = cc => {
  return '#'.repeat(cc.length - 4) + cc.substr(-4);
}

console.log(maskify("abcdefghijklmnop")); 
//logs "############mnop"
```

Comment: I'm trying to run it on Codewars, it worked on my machine too. I'm not sure why it's returning that error :(

Answer (score 0):

Both code snippets produce same results. If the parameter length is less than 4, it will error-out.

```js
let maskify = cc => console.log('#'.repeat(cc.length - 4) + cc.substr(-4));
maskify('1234123456785678'); // Masks first 12 digits
maskify('12341'); // Masks first digit
maskify('123'); // Invalid count value error
```

```js
let maskify = cc => {
  return '#'.repeat(cc.length - 4) + cc.substr(-4);
};
// Same results as previous code
console.log(maskify('1234123456785678')); // Masks first 12 digits
console.log(maskify('12341')); // Masks first digit
console.log(maskify('123')); // Invalid count error
```

**How it works**

- First the parameter `cc` needs to be at least 4 chars length (typically, it may be 16 chars length)
- The `'#'.repeat()` instructs that the character `#` needs to be `repeat`-ed.
- The parameter sent to `repeat` tells how many times. So, `cc.length - 4` indicates that for `cc` of 16 chars, there will be 12 `'#'` repeated
- The `+` seeks to concatenate the repeated `'#'`s with the operand on its right
- The `cc.substr(-4)` extracts the last 4 characters from `cc` (& this is the operand on the right-side of `+` for concatenation).

Both the snippets do the same logic. The first one logs to the `console`; while the second one returns the string.

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, this is what I thought too. For some reason the kata won't take the one that returns a value, even though that's what it needs me to do.